# JS send formData with multiple files to java API

Tags: java

I am new in JAVA, and I am trying to create a java api receiving array of files from JS frontend. but I get "415 Unsupported media type error". I am not sure what kind of class or library I can use for that. Below is my JAVA API code

```
@POST
@Timed
@Path("/prepare_file_segments")
@Produces({"application/json"})
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> prepareFileSegments(
        @FormDataParam("files") FormDataMultiPart bodyParts,
        @Context HttpServletRequest request
) {
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> headers = new ArrayList<>();
    for (BodyPart part : bodyParts.getBodyParts()) {
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = part.getEntityAs(InputStream.class);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String[] headerRow = bufferedReader.readLine().split("\t");
            List<String> list = Arrays.asList(headerRow);
            ArrayList header = new ArrayList(list);
            headers.add(header);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            log.error("prepareFileSegments failed " + e.getMessage());
            throw new FileNotFoundException(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("prepareFileSegments failed " + e.getMessage());
            throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return headers;
}
```

here is the wretch call I used in React

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('files', FILES)
wretch('url')
.json(formData)
.post()
.json()
```

im not able to use debugger at this moment. this kinda block me a little bit. But am I doing this correct ? what class and library should I use for this api ? can someone give me an example ? thank you